# IAppBuilder could not be found

Tags: owin

I read the previous posts - Tried a few things.
Here is the issue
A simple console OWIN self host app - Not much in there
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
does not compile.
 1. If I say using Microsoft.Owin and using Owin, then I get an error the using directive for owin already appeared. I can't figure out why.
 2. If I do using Microsoft.Owin but modify the use as Owin.IAppBuilder
then the compiler says it can't find owin.IAppBuilder.

Yes I tried reinstalling Microsoft.Owin
and Owin (3 times)
I checked the project reference 4.5.1

Answer (score 4):

Here is an issue to consider.

1. If your using statements are insider a namespace declaration
2. And your name space starts with Microsoft (for whatever reasons)

Then using Owin ==> looks at Microsoft.Owin
The solution is to use using global::Owin;

Comment: Wow, I found so many comments which not work for me, and this save me finally. Thanks.